# When writting a networked application, how do I choose a good port number?

Tags: ports

I'm writing a network application that will be using a defined port communication.  Is there a best practice for picking which port number to standardize my default port on?

Comment: Pick your birth year*10 and google to see whether it is used in another application.

Comment: @khachik post that as an answer :P

Comment: What protocol is listening? If your app is HTTP or HTTPS based, the usual ports are best. People that deploy with other servers will know how to handle their port usage.